# How can I get all the possible conditions for a second-order equation?

Tags: equation-solving, conditional

I have the following equation:

```
Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]
```

I want to gain three cases for this equation.

If delta be $b^2 -4ac$

For $delta>0$: $x =(-b + Sqrt[b^2 -4ac])/(2a)$ and $x =(-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4ac])/(2a)$

For $delta=0$: $x =(-b)/(2a)$

For $delta<0$: $x=(-b + i Sqrt[delta])/(2a)$ and $x=(-b - i Sqrt[delta])/(2a)$.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Maybe to write a Piecewise function would look like you want ...

Comment: You can't do what you are asking for. If `a,b,c` are symbolic, how is Mathematica supposed to find out if `b^2-4 a c` is positive or negative or zero?? Using Solve gives conditional expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question implicitly assumes that the three parameters are real and that `a != 0`.  So, to proceed these assumptions must be given explicitly to Mathematica.

```
Simplify[Solve[{a x^2 + b x + c == 0, (a | b | c) ∈ Reals, a != 0}, x], 
    (a | b | c) ∈ Reals && a != 0]

(* {{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/2 (-(b/a) - (I Sqrt[-b^2 + 4 a c])/Abs[a]), 
            b^2 < 4 a c && c != 0]}, 
    {x -> ConditionalExpression[1/2 (-(b/a) + (I Sqrt[-b^2 + 4 a c])/Abs[a]),
            b^2 < 4 a c && c != 0]}, 
    {x -> ConditionalExpression[-((b + (a Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/Abs[a])/(2 a)), 
            c != 0 && 4 a c < b^2]}, 
    {x -> ConditionalExpression[(-b + (a Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/Abs[a])/(2 a), 
            c != 0 && 4 a c < b^2]}} *)
```

which correctly gives both general solutions.  (`x == -b/2a` for `b^2 == 4 a c` is a special case of the general solutions, and one should not expect Mathematica to single it out.)  Strangely, Mathematica has introduced unnecessary conditions, which easily can be removed, if desired.

```
Flatten[% /. {Abs[a] -> a, c != 0 -> True}]

(* {x -> ConditionalExpression[1/2 (-(b/a) - (I Sqrt[-b^2 + 4 a c])/a), b^2 < 4 a c], 
    x -> ConditionalExpression[1/2 (-(b/a) + (I Sqrt[-b^2 + 4 a c])/a), b^2 < 4 a c], 
    x -> ConditionalExpression[-((b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)), 4 a c < b^2], 
    x -> ConditionalExpression[(-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a), 4 a c < b^2] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

here,

```
Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x, Reals]

Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x, Complexes]
```